# How do I run a python script using PHP on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: php, raspberry-pi

I want to run a python script on Raspberry Pi via web-app. I have a PHP page for a button, and when the button is clicked it goes to another PHP page which is made up of the following code. If I type `system("mkdir folder")` it does work but it does not work for a python script. I have already changed the `sudeors` file using `www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`.

## PHP file

```
<?php
    system("sudo python3 x.py");
?>
```

## Python Script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
os.system("gnome-terminal")
```

Comment: What is the output? Since `system` only shows stdout not stderr, you can use `echo system("sudo python3 x.py 2>&1");`

Comment: Use absolute paths for both the `python3`-binary and the python file. Also check that the user the web server runs with has access to execute the python binary + the file.

Comment: @cmbuckley I tried and I got this in the browser: `Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display: Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I added absolute paths for both files and I got this: `sudo: /usr/bin/env/python3: command not found sudo: /usr/bin/env/python3: command not found`. On checking the permission rights for the python script, I got this: 
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data  105 Jan 16 15:44 send.php`
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root     root       62 Jan 16 15:32 x.py`.

Comment: The absolute path of python3 isn't `/usr/bin/env/python3`; `/usr/bin/env python3` (with a space) determines the path without having to hardcode the actual path (which may be `/usr/bin/python3`). It looks like [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768508/cant-launch-graphical-apps-from-terminal-after-updating-to-15-10) might help, but it's also really unclear what you're trying to achieve: a PHP script is launching a Python script to open a graphical terminal emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

`<?php echo shell_exec("python x.py");?>`

This command should `echo` out the result of the executed command, useful for debugging since it will show errors that you might have either in the shell command or in the python script.

or

`<?php echo exec("python x.py");?>`

See [this](http://php.net/manual/es/function.shell-exec.php) and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Also make sure and verify that your `php` engine has enough permissions to run shell commands. You could also try to disable [safe-mode](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) but it is deprecated and not recommended by any means.

Also from the comments in the references:

> If you are running php as an Apache module in Unix then every system command you run is run as user apache.  This just makes sense.. Unix won't allow privileges to be elevated in this manner.  If you need to run a system command with elevated privileges think through the problem carefully!

---

As a side note, if you are trying to have an interactive webpage where you input stuff in it and it acts as a remote terminal shell that is defenitely not how to do it, it is a bit more complicated since it would require bidirectional connection in """" real time """". You would have to use some `AJAX` or a `WebSocket` connection with a `WebSocket` server on your raspi.